# Client Android app freeze on thread.start()

Tags: android, multithreading

As i said before my app always crash when i try to start the thread, i tryed to comment some part of the code and i'm almost sure that the problem is in the starting of the thread

```
    public class MouseTestActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
        Thread mainThread;
        String ip;
        ObjectOutputStream  oos;
        Socket clientSocket;
        myRunnable runProcess;

            class myRunnable implements Runnable{
                String ip;
                ObjectOutputStream  oos;
                Socket clientSocket;
                myRunnable(String ip){
                    this.ip = ip;
                }

                public void ScriviPosizione(float x,float y){
                    try{
                        this.oos.writeUTF(x+"-"+y+"\n");

                        this.oos.flush();
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        System.out.println("Eccezione!! "+e);
                    }
                }


                public void run()
                {
                    try {
                        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        text.setText(this.ip);
                        this.clientSocket = new Socket(this.ip, 4000);
                        System.out.println(this.ip); 
                        this.oos = new ObjectOutputStream (this.clientSocket.getOutputStream());                        
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("Eccezione!! "+e);

                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_mouse_test);


            Intent intent = getIntent();
            this.ip = intent.getStringExtra("ip");

            this.runProcess = new myRunnable(this.ip);

            mainThread = new Thread(this.runProcess );
            setupActionBar();
            GestureOverlayView c = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.overlayView1);
            c.setOnTouchListener(this);
            this.mainThread.start();


        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        private void setupActionBar() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mouse_test, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){          
            //this.runProcess.ScriviPosizione(event.getX(),event.getY());
            int action = event.getAction();
            if ( action == event.ACTION_MOVE){
                this.runProcess.ScriviPosizione(event.getX(), event.getY());
            }

            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            text.setText("ciccio");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:

                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

does someone has some advice ? Thank's

That's the LogCat

03-17 10:03:02.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1276): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-86

03-17 10:03:02.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1276): Process: com.example.clientandroid, PID: 1276

03-17 10:03:02.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1276): java.lang.NullPointerException

03-17 10:03:02.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1276):     at com.example.clientandroid.MouseTestActivity$myRunnable.run(MouseTestActivity.java:54)

03-17 10:03:02.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1276):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Comment: Please post your logcat output. Otherwise it will be difficult to identify the problem.

Comment: 1/ freeze != crash. 2/ you are accessing the view in another thread. You'd know that if you only took the time to look at the exception message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not execute the following line

```
text.setText(this.ip);
```

on a Thread different from the UI Thread. Only the UI Thread can "touch" the UI. Since you are inside an `Activity` you can use `runOnUiThread`, to execute that code on the UI Thread

Comment: @user3350874 If this answers your question please close the question by accepting the answer.